# Methods to identify duplicate questions on Twitter?

Tags: algorithm, twitter, duplicates

As stated in the title, I'm simply looking for algorithms or solutions one might use to take in the twitter firehose (or a portion of it) and

a) identify questions in general
b) for a question, identify questions that could be the same, with some degree of confidence

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(A)**

I would try to identify questions using [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) and the [Bag of Words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

1. Create a labeled set of twits, and label each of them with a binary
   flag: question or not question.
2. Extract the features from the training set. The features are traditionally words, but at least for any time I tried it - using [bi-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) significantly improved the results. (3-grams were not helpful for my cases).
3. Build a classifier from the data. I usually found out [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) gives better performance then other classifiers, but you can use others as well - such as [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) or [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) (But you will probably need [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) algorithm for these).
4. Now you can use your classifier to classify a tweet.<sup>1</sup>

**(B)**

This issue is referred in the world of [Information-Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) as "duplicate detection" or "near-duplicate detection".

You can at least find questions which are very similar to each other using Semantic Interpretation, as described by Markovitch and Gabrilovich  in their wonderful article [Wikipedia-based Semantic Interpretation for Natural Language Processing](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Eshaulm/papers/abstracts/Gabrilovich-2009-WBS.html). At the very least, it will help  you identify if two questions are discussing the same issues (even though not identical).

The idea goes like this:

1. Use wikipedia to build a vector that represents its semantics, for a term `t`, the entry `vector_t[i]` is the tf-idf score of the term `i` as it co-appeared with the term `t`. The idea is described in details in the article. Reading the 3-4 first pages are enough to understand it. No need to read it all.<sup>2</sup>
2. For each tweet, construct a vector which is a function of the vectors of its terms. Compare between two vectors - and you can identify if two questions are discussing the same issues.

**EDIT:**

On 2nd thought, the BoW model is not a good fit here, since it ignores the position of terms. However, I believe if you add [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) processing for extracting feature (for examples, for each term, also denote if it is pre-subject or post-subject, and this was determined using NLP procssing), combining with Machine Learning will yield pretty good results.

---

(1) For evaluation of your classifier, you can use [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29), and check the expected accuracy.

(2) I know Evgeny Gabrilovich  published the implemented algorithm they created as an open source project, just need to look for it.

Comment: +1 In other words: **Learn NLP - Natural Language Processing** =P

Comment: @Keyne: Actually it is not NLP, it is statistical based method. And on 2nd thought, I don't think the BoW model is a good fit (since determining if something is a question heavily relies on the *position* of a word). However, I believe using some NLP based approach to extract the features will be very promising when combined with SVM.

Comment: I meant: Almost everything you pointed out here is part of NLP Toolkits (e.g. [Python' NLTK](https://sites.google.com/site/naturallanguagetoolkit/book))